# How to enable audio when using VideoCapturePlayer?

Tags: wpf, wpf-mediakit

I am trying to integrate a live feed in my WPF application using DirectShow device. Both audio and video is working fine in VLC. 
I have integrated `VideoCapturePlayer` from the WPF-MediaKit in a simple application and i am able to see live video feed from the device, but i am unable to get the audio. I am not 100% sure that it is possible to capture both audio and video using the `VideoCapturePlayer`.
Any help in getting the audio to work will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's no Audio renderer set up in `VideoCapturePlayer`. Try to pull up the `MediaUriBase.InsertAudioRenderer` into the `MediaPlayerBase` and use it for the `VideoCapturePlayer`. If you succeed, [open a new PR](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/pulls) with your code.

Comment: You are right, there in no audio renderer in  VideoCapturePlayer. i am working on adding it in MediaPlayerBase. Will update the question if i am successful.

Comment: @moeed I am also looking for the same. I need to record a video with sound. Were you able to achieve this? Can you please suggest how to do if you were successful.